# How can I connect to sftp using linux command from Perl

Tags: linux, perl

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
system("cd $PATH
/usr/bin/sftp mysite.com <<!EOF
put sample.txt
bye
!EPF");
```

When i complile tha application, it asking the pasword, 
how to pass the user/password in the code itself,

what i want is, my script should not ask the password. i want to set the user/password in the code itself.
user command not working in sftp
How to make it.

Comment: Could you elaborate, and show what you have done so far?

Comment: you will always be prompted for a password with sftp unless you set up public-key authentication with ssh-agent,

Comment: there is way in shell, that is called "expect"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With such a vague question its hard to give more of an answer…

Have you tried the [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP) module?

EDIT:

Based on the edit to the question - try using Net::SFTP::Foreign

```
    use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
    use warnings;
    use strict;

    my $host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, user => 'user', password => 'pass');
    $sftp->error and die "Something bad happened: " . $sftp->error;
    $sftp->put("sample.txt", "/home/test/test") or die "put failed: " . $sftp->error;
```

You should get a more meaningful error message and you can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try other modules, e.g [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign) or the SFTP functionality of [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH2).